# How to move C# form legend with mouse?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, customization

I am creating a plotting program and I was wondering how to move a chart's legend with the mouse? So you would click on the legend and then you could move it anywhere inside the chart area.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer without seeing what code you have thus far... or even seeing [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Is you legend a picturebox control or what?

Comment: I've been trying to use a hit test method but I haven't really found anything concrete. I've been looking up how to use that method and have gotten as far as `public void HitTest(object s, EventArgs e){Point MouseP = MousePosition; //Then somehow say if mouse is on legend and clicking allow legend to move }`

Answer (score 0):

Using manual double-buffering of the chart, draw the legend at the current mouse position (perhaps + (15,15)) on the back-buffer just prior to drawing the back buffer to the screen. You can also set an Alpha to make the legend semi-transparent until the user drops it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a little form without borders to build your legend or use a ToolTip item. Then you could move with mouseMove event:

```
    private void frmMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            ChangeLegendPosition(e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

Where ChangeLegendPosition is your function that updates your form/tooltip position.